# Mocking ExecutionContext in Azure queue trigger function unit tests

Tags: azure, unit-testing, azure-functions

How can I mock ExecutionContext when testing a queue trigger function? Below is the sample function where I am using ExecutionContext to getting some setting values which I use further down the function, I will need to provide testing values for these settings as well.

```
[FunctionName("ProcessQueueFunction")]
public static void Run([QueueTrigger("process-queue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string queueItem, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
{
   var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
       .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
       .AddEnvironmentVariables()
       .Build();

       var customConfiguraion = config.GetSection("CustomSection");

       //do stuff...
}
```

I can do something link this but that gives me error on the FunctionAppDirectory being invalid or empty. What do I need to set FunctionAppDirectory to? or is this an incorrect way to do this?

```
var mockContext = new Mock<ExecutionContext>();
mockContext.Object.FunctionAppDirectory = string.Empty; //or any other value

ProcessQueueFunction.Run("TestQueueItem", log: logger, context: mockContext.Object);
```

Comment: use dependency injection and pass CustomSection in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks. I am following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#working-with-options-and-settings) which works for settings like "Values": { "MyOptions:MyCustomSetting": "Foobar" } but won't work for "MyOptions": { "MyCustomSetting": "Foobar" }. Any ideas?

Comment: I ended up following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56500317/965676)

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass Execution Context, no need to mock a class just to use a property.

```
ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
executionContext.FunctionAppDirectory = "PATH";

ProcessQueueFunction.Run("TestQueueItem", log: logger, context: executionContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
executionContext.FunctionAppDirectory = "";

ProcessQueueFunction.Run("ProcessFile", log: logger, context: executionContext);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecutionContext` belongs to NuGet `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext`.
And you can mock `FunctionAppDirectory` like so:

```cs
var mockContext = new Mock<Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext>();
mockContext 
    .Setup(x => x.FunctionAppDirectory)
    .Returns(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()); // Add your directory value inside Returns

var theContextObject = mockContext.Object;
```

`theContextObject` is the object instance you can pass in. When `FunctionAppDirectory` is called, your current directory is going to be returned. You can tweak inside of `Returns` according to what you want `FunctionAppDirectory` to be returned.