# Local Azure Functions load local.settings.json from Core Tools Runtime folder and not from Working Directory

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I am working on several Azure Functions v4 with .net6.0 at the moment.
When trying to start the App locally, I realized that my local.settings.json is not properly loaded.

Before continuing, here is how I load the configuration in the Startup class.

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            var dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            // dir is $projectPath\bin\Debug\net6.0
            builder.Services.AddFunctions(configuration);
        }
    }
```

The file `local.settings.json` is in the working directory.
When debugging into `configuration.Providers[0].Data`, I can see that nothing has been loaded.

When debugging further I can see `configuration.Providers[0].Source.FileProvider.Root` points to  `%localAppData%\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.35.0\cli_x64`.

Of course everything works fine, when I put my settings file in this path. But I don't understand why the functions core tools load it from there.
Moreover I am working on several functions, all having their own settings. This would force me to manually copy the json files every time in this folder.

Any know, why this is the case?

Comment: Right click on your `local.ettings.json` file and check what is the value of the `Copy to Output Directory` has ?

Comment: It has the value "Copy if newer".

Comment: So,do you have `local.settings.json` file other than in working directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `local.settings.json` will be on the application root directory.

[image]

> Local Azure Functions not from Working Directory

- We can set the Working Directory in the `Debug` => `General`.
- Right click on the Application Root folder => `Properties` =>`Debug` => `General` => `Working Directory`.
- Select the Application root path.

[image]

- As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash#start), we can use `func start` to set the path.
- Also check the `launchSettings.json` file which specifies the `workingDirectory` path.

```cs
{
  "profiles": {
    "FunctionApp3": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "--port 7132",
      "workingDirectory": "C:\\Users\\****\\source\\repos\\April\\FunctionApp3"
    }
  }
}
```

- Iam able to load `local.settings.json` file without any issues.
- Set the `localSetting` key-value in `local.settings.json`.

```cs
  {
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "localSetting": "Value from local.settings.json file"
  }
}
```

- `.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` is missing in the `Startup` file.

My `Startup.cs`:

```cs
using FunctionApp3;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.IO;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace FunctionApp3
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {

            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables()
           .Build();

            builder.Services.AddSingleton(configuration);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks [Azure functions local.settings.json represented in appsettings.json for a ServiceBusTrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008309/azure-functions-local-settings-json-represented-in-appsettings-json-for-a-servic) for the reference.

***`Function1.cs` file:***

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace FunctionApp3
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        public Function1(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _config = configuration;

        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
      
            var localsetting = _config["localSetting"];
            var runtime = _config["FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME"]; 

            var localsetting1 = _config.GetValue<string>("localSetting");
            log.LogInformation(localsetting);
                
            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
                : $"Hello, {localsetting}.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

***Output:***

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, other duties came in between, but I was able to verify it now.
What helped me and is presumably the best solution for us is using the ".SetBasePath(...)".
No other working directory was set, neither in the csproj file nor in the launchSettings.json. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad that the issue is resolved.